# Javascript - copy all html code into clipboard

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am making an app which has to check an information from a special webpage. What I need to do is to pass the html content from this page to my existing program, and it does all the rest.

The website where I get the data works in IE8 and newer, so it kinda narrows the problem. I need to make an extension for IE which could copy ALL the html code from the page it has been called from (and save it into a .txt, in the best case), so result would be as on the example:

```
<html>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

I know how to make such extensions, the only problem is javascript: I am a newbie. Are there any short solutions for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are many options available

1) using XMLSerializer

```
var Source = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
```

2)

```
   document.documentElement.outerHTML
   or

   document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

```js
function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
  textArea.style.top = 0;
  textArea.style.left = 0;
  textArea.style.width = '2em';
  textArea.style.height = '2em';
  textArea.style.padding = 0;
  textArea.style.border = 'none';
  textArea.style.outline = 'none';
  textArea.style.boxShadow = 'none';
  textArea.style.background = 'transparent';
  textArea.value = text;
  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.select();
  try {
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    console.log('Copying text command was ' + msg);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
  }
  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnDate").click(function() {
    var allHTML = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    copyTextToClipboard(allHTML);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btnDate" class="btn btn-primary">Copy HTML
</button>
```